# it is possible to custom input field on admin panel?

Tags: admin-panel, ce-1.9.2.2, taxes

It is possible to  custom input field on admin panel?

[image]

How can I add and remove  input field on `Items ordered - Admin panel`.

**Admin panel > Sale > Orders > View > Order view > Items ordered**

Answer (score 0):

Subha, You can add this two fields at sales order view page at admin.

see below as reference:

http://www.webspeaks.in/2015/12/magento-add-custom-block-in-admin-sales-order-page.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15426432/how-we-add-new-comment-field-to-admin-order-view-page

[Add custom block to admin order view](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/74134/add-custom-block-to-admin-order-view)

---

But **basic of those fields**, order Calculation is too Ricky as you want to recalculate order items and order totals.

First see ,[Is it possible to update order item price and order total after order is place](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/42452/is-it-possible-to-update-order-item-price-and-order-total-after-order-is-place)

As per as, my thought **price change after order place is not an  identical idea** for an order. bcoz of **depends on lot of  functions magento order price is calculated**.

If you want to change product price after order place then **it become too Ricky and unsecured**